# How to localize push notifications using Expo

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently working on a Expo project and I've setup the expo-server-sdk on my google-cloud-functions to send push notifications. The implementation worked but now I'm stuck on how to localize my notifications.

I'm currently only supporting two languages on my mobile application. I was thinking about just persisting the locale of each user in my Firestore but I'm not sure if there are better ways of implementing that.